# Django Tutorial: name 'HttpResponse' is not defined

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django via their tutorial for [getting started](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/). I have looked at other `Django Tutorial` errors and did not see this one (although I did not search every listing).

I have made the changes to `mysite/urls.py` and `polls/urls.py` exactly as they demonstrate and I have run the server command:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I get the following error:
[image]

Since I am new to Django, I do not know what is going on. Please help.

Comment: You can use also [`django.shortcuts`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/) it will save you more time and your code will be more elegant and easy to maintain.
Otherwise, you need to import `from django.http import HttpResponse`.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
```

in your views file at the top

Answer (score 9):

Put this import in your poll/views.py before using HttpResponse.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
```

Answer (score 4):

`from django.http import HttpResponse`
add this line on the top of polls/views.py file. I am new too, and had the same error. good Luck and i see u around.

Answer (score 1):

in your polls/views.py

By default is :

`from django.shortcuts import render`

change to:

`from django.shortcuts import render,HttpResponse`

this will call the HttpResponse class

Answer (score 0):

I had imported `HttpResponse` and still got this error.

If you use Apache server as your primary server for web, try restarting Apache and reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the import was there, but when I called HttpsResponse I called it with small h as a typo instead of the capital H

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
def home(request):
      return HttpResponse("Hello!") #==> This one was with httpResponse so the same error been received.
```

Comment: This just reiterates the accepted answer from 2017 except highlighting that you made a typo. At best it should be a comment about the command being case-sensitive, but that's a rather generous take.

Answer (score -1):

For me it was because I used singe quotes (') instead of double quotes (")

Comment: This is a typo that other people probably won't make. At best it's perhaps comment material. OP also doesn't have quotes of either type in their scenario, so this is also at best unrelated to the problem.

Answer (score -1):

1. Check your import statement.
2. Check your function. I had "HttpsResponse" instead of "HttpResponse"

Good luck.

Comment: This just reiterates the accepted answer from 2017.